# deal shuffled cards to 4 players in C#

Tags: c#

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string[] odeck = { "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10", "CJ", "CQ", "CK", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "H7", "H8", "H9", "H10", "HJ", "HQ", "HK", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10", "SJ", "SQ", "SK", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "DJ", "DQ", "DK" };
    public string[] sdeck; // array to store the shuffled deck
    const  int cards_length = 51;
    //string[] cards = new string[odeck.Length];
    Random random = new Random();
    const int hand = 13; //number of cards in each player hand
    const int numPlayers = 4; //number of players
    string[,] players = new string[numPlayers, hand];    // Set up players hands arrays


    public void shuffle()
    {
        for (int i = odeck.Length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int rand = random.Next(i);
            string temp = odeck[rand];
            odeck[rand] = odeck[i - 1];
            odeck[i - 1] = temp;
        }

    }

    public void deal() //iam having trouble how to write this function
    {
        // deal the deck
        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < hand; j++)
            {
                players[i, j] = ;
            }
        }
    }
private void GetNewDeck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < odeck.Length; i++)
        {
            string deck = odeck[i];

            NewDecktextBox.Text = String.Join("  ", odeck);

        }

    }
  private void Shufflebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 myshuffle = new Form1();
        myshuffle.shuffle();
        sdeck = myshuffle.odeck;
        ShuffletextBox.Text = String.Join("  ", sdeck);
    }
private void Dealbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // having issue with this
    {
      Player1textBox.Text =
      Player2textBox.Text = 
      Player3textBox3.Text =
      Player4textBox.Text= 

    }
```

Hi iam creating a card game which creates a new deck,shuffles the deck and deal the shuffled deck to 4 players. I was able to finish creating a new deck(with the click of a GetNewDeckButton) and shuffling the deck(ShuffleButton) , but doesn't know how to write the deal function.. when I click the deal button the shuffled cards should be displayed on each players textboxes (each player should receive 13 cards )(player1textbox,palyer2textbox.....) Can somebody guide me through this?

Thank you

Comment: Try to phrase your question in a more direct, single question fashion. What *exactly* does it need to do? What have you tried? Where did it fail? It is better to come to SO after you have attempted something rather than asking for a first pass explanation of how to deal cards. Maybe even try a little pseudo-code for your first pass :)!

Comment: I'd suggest using [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) data structure for a deck of cards and nor an array

Comment: The Related section to the right of this question shows a bunch of questions asking about dealing cards.

Comment: @VP I Was able to finish the newdeck creation and shuffling the deck but having trouble to deal the shuffled deck to 4 players...when I click the deal button the cards should be distributed to 4 players(each get 13)... in their respective textboxes

Comment: As a side note, capitalize those functions of yours, especially public ones. Also, you might consider making a `Card` class into which you could just stuff a char (for number) and enum (for suite).

Answer (score 0):

You need a way of removing the top card from the deck. Then you can just go round the table 13 times dealing each player the top card in turn (edit: I see you already have that part).

Currently you are representing your deck as an array. The problem there is that it's fixed length so there's no straight forward way to remove the top card. What you could do is store the index of the top card in a variable and reduce that each time you take a card. Something like:

```
int topCardIndex=51;

string RemoveTopCard()
{
   string topCard = sdeck[topCardIndex];
   topCardIndex--;
   return topCard;
}
```

Which is used like:

```
public void deal() //iam having trouble how to write this function
{
    // deal the deck
    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < hand; j++)
        {
            players[i, j] = RemoveTopCard();
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend you create a separate class called Deck to encapsulate all the Deck stuff including the shuffling.